# WPF FlowDocumentPageViewer

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, documentpaginator

I have custom implementation of `DocumentPaginator` (include header and footer) and I want to use this paginor in `FlowDocumentPageViewer.`

How can I do it?
I've tried to implement **IDocumentPaginatorSource** in my custom DocumentPaginator, but FlowDocumentPageViewer throw exception: `"FlowDocumentPageViewer supports only FlowDocument as content."`